# Load OpenLayers Map Asynchronously onto SharePoint Page

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, asynchronous, openlayers

I have an OpenLayers map that is being built on a SharePoint page. Everything works just fine, but the map takes a while to load, thus freezing the rest of the page until it is finished. This map is intended for our home page and cannot be added until I fix this issue.

I have tried JQuery .load and .ajax to load an html file with all of the markup, but both of these throw an "Access Denied" error when trying to load OpenLayers.js. The work around for this was to first include all of the .js files in the SharePoint page that was making the .load or .ajax call. using the .done() method, I would add the retrieved source code to a placeholder DIV on the page. Once the .done() method ran, page load would freeze until it was complete.

I do understand that once it the ajax call returns the response, it still has to add the objects to the placeholder DIV and build the markers and layers onto the OpenLayers map, thus causing the freeze.

I tried to load an Iframe with the OpenLayers map, but it too freezes the page until it is completely loaded.

Is there any way to completely load an openlayers map and all of its components before loading it to a page? Possibly in another window? Using a web service?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OpenLayers needs a dom element(div) to create map so there's no way you can create a map without div-element in place.

The only optimisation I can think if is that you load OpenLayers library and code that creates map in the bottom of the page, below all other html on the page. This way, script won't start executing until the rest of the page is loaded. This is a very common best practise for javascript in general, not only OpenLayers.

If you are using WebParts to package a map and absolutely can't have a map in the bottom of the page then you'll probably have to create 2 WebParts - one that renders div-elemnt where you want map to be rendered and another that imports OpenLayers library and runs javascript that renders the map.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this out, but the page still froze as the Geometry is drawn on the map.

The solution I am working on now handles most of the JS in a new window. This works great until I need to pass OpenLayer objects between windows. It reads string properties just fine, but objects suchas Layers or Features don't play very nice.

Comment: I have also tried to serialize the objects with JSON, JQuery, Openlayers.Format.JSON().serailize.object() but couldn't get anything going. "Openlayers.Format.JSON().serailize.object()" takes an extremely long time to render.

What it all boils down to is this :
When an object is added to the map, it has to be rendered to the page. Adding a polygon with 100+ points can be a drag. I don't think there is any "Asynchronous" way to render these to the page, but I hope someone might know of one lol.